# How to use stacked bar chart with no space between bars which are one over another in a vertical chart?

Tags: javascript, plotly, bar-chart, plotly.js

I have a Plotly.js chart and there is a minor design issue described below with screenshots.

This is how it looks like right now:

[image: version1]

And this is how it looks with `layout.bargap` set to 0:

[image: version2]

I would like to keep the horizontal spacing but without the vertical spacing between the bars that are one over another.

## What I have tried

I have tried setting `layout.bargroupgap` to `0` but it has no effect in this context.

I also tried these things but they did not work as I wished:

```js
this.context.updateContainer({
  // 'marker.line.color': '#000',
  // 'marker.line.width': -1, // or 0
  // 'selected.marker.opacity': 0,
  // 'unselected.marker.opacity': 0,
});
```

The project on which I am working is [here](https://github.com/eea/volto-plotlycharts/tree/categorical_colors) but I do not know what part of it is of interest.

There are no error messages.

Thank you.